# SAML with simpleSAMLphp as SP and OpenAM as IdP

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0, openam, simplesamlphp

So I'm doing this just to test that my SAML configuration on OpenAM works fine. I've installed simpleSAMLphp, followed the installation instructions (although I skipped the '''certs''' part). And then I found this tutorial that is great OpenAM simpleSAMLphp tutorial][1](http://packtlib.packtpub.com/library/open-source-identity-management-patterns-and-practices-using-openam-10-x/ch06lvl1sec39#)

Now everything seems to work fine, when I choose to log-in using OpenAM, it redirects me to OpenAM's login page, I type in my username and password, and then I get redirected to SimpleSAMLphp with the following exception :

```
SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Backtrace:
0 /var/www/html/services/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:180 (N/A)
Caused by: Exception: Reference validation failed
Backtrace:
8 /var/www/html/services/simplesamlphp/vendor/robrichards/xmlseclibs/xmlseclibs.php:1056 (XMLSecurityDSig::validateReference)
7 /var/www/html/services/simplesamlphp/vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/Utils.php:54 (SAML2_Utils::validateElement)
6 /var/www/html/services/simplesamlphp/vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/Assertion.php:517 (SAML2_Assertion::parseSignature)
5 /var/www/html/services/simplesamlphp/vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/Assertion.php:247 (SAML2_Assertion::__construct)
4 /var/www/html/services/simplesamlphp/vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/Response.php:37 (SAML2_Response::__construct)
3 /var/www/html/services/simplesamlphp/vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/Message.php:509 (SAML2_Message::fromXML)
2 /var/www/html/services/simplesamlphp/vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/HTTPPost.php:76 (SAML2_HTTPPost::receive)
1 /var/www/html/services/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php:16 (require)
0 /var/www/html/services/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:135 (N/A)
```

I've checked things up before I post my message here, OpenAM's SAML Response seems fine, it gets stuck in Assertion.php file.

I've really tried everything and it just got to the point where it's giving me hard headaches, I don't want to go through SimpleSAMLphp's code.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: For simapleSAMLphp issues, I've found the forum to be the best route - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/simplesamlphp

Comment: Thank you :) I'm gonna try to post there and copy the answer (if I get any)

Comment: The Firefox SAML tracer plugin is handy for debugging these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that the attributes which are passed from OpenAM are in not uri format. can you capture the SAML request from SP and Response from IDP and post it. That will help to see what is been requested and whats been provided.